# JOptionPane component placement

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have a JOptionPane dialog that looks like this.

[image]

I want the checkbox to be right under the icon like this.

[image]

Is it possible with JOptionPane or do I have to create my own dialog box?

This is the code for the first image.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    box.add(new JLabel("TEXT"));
    box.add(new JCheckBox("Check box text"));

    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            box,
            "TITLE",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
}
```

Comment: You will have to create your own dialog.  You can make use of JOptionPane’s icon by retrieving it with `UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.questionIcon")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a PLAIN_MESSAGE and then display the Icon in your panel:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    JPanel first = new JPanel( new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.LEFT) );
    first.add( new JLabel( UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.questionIcon" ) ) );
    first.add(new JLabel("TEXT"));
    JPanel box = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 1) );
    box.add(first);
    box.add(new JCheckBox("Check box text"));

    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            box,
            "TITLE",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE
            );

}
```